# Is there no Google App Engine interactive console with Golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

There is a Google App Engine interactive console with Python.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_interactive_console

But in `Go` documents there is no information for it.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/using-local-server#using_the_interactive_console

The interactive console with `Go` is not yet implemented?

Answer (score 2):

Though Go is compiled and not interpreted language, there’re several projects

https://github.com/c-bata/go-prompt

https://github.com/mkouhei/gosh